# Given n line segments on the plane which are either vertical or horizontal. How to count intersections between these line segments?

Tags: algorithm

I have seen solutions involving sweeping line methods. But I need a divide and conquer method.
Basically i want to know if we divide the plane vertically into two subplanes and then try to solve the questions on both planes, do we have to take some special step in merging?

Would there be any special advantage of using divide and conquer in this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only special steps would be handling vertical lines on the division line, and breaking divided horizontal line segments.

Comment: I think this should solve it, so please correct me while try to make the recurrence relationship, which is as follows: 1. divide problem T(n) in 2 parts, each of size T(n/2). 2. while merging we need to check all the vertical lines on the dividing line and horizontal lines in which are crossing the division line. It should take order of n time. So the recurrence relation would be => T(n) = T(n/2) + cN. which gives us T(n) = O(n lg n). Is this correct ?

Comment: There are two parts, so the recursion is T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cN.  Also note that splitting things in half is somewhat hard to do (but can be done in O(n)).  OTOH, you could just sort it once ahead of time, and then it's easy to split in half (but then also easy to solve via sweepline).